# '90s-2000s TV series about two teenagers who find an old book and end up inhabiting the bodies of famous figures from history/mythology

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

I remember watching this as a child and can not for the life of me remember the name and it’s driving me crazy.

The show consisted of a teenage boy in a wheelchair and his neighbor, a teenage girl, who somehow come into possession of this old book they find. They start reading and looking at it (I can't remember if it showed projected onto the wall or if they were just reading it in the book) but ultimately they get sucked back in time and their minds get transferred into people from the past.

There was an episode where the boy goes into "Jason's" body when he was fighting the Minotaur. They get sucked back to medieval times, and there's also an episode where they get sucked back in time to Egyptian times. And I remember him wanting to stay in that time because the first time they went back he could walk and wasn’t bound to the wheelchair and he was really excited.

If I'm remembering correctly, that might have been the same woman that played Joan in *Joan of Arcadia*. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

As per [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265501/90-s-2000-s-tv-series-boy-in-a-wheelchair-finds-a-book-that-sends-him-back-in-t/265502#comment731674_265502) from the OP, this is ***[MythQuest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273374/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (2001).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythQuest):

> *MythQuest* is a Canadian television series that originally aired on PBS in 2001. Produced by Mind's Eye Entertainment, **it stars Meredith Henderson and Christopher Jacot as Cleo and Alex Bellows, two teens whose father Matt disappears into the Cyber Museum, a computer program that, as they discover, allows them to travel into myths by touching an artifact on the screen.**
>
> **They become characters in the myths, and strive to keep the myth to its normal progression; a difficult task when confronted by Gorgos, a trickster god who appears in each myth to try to change it.** Alex's initial journey into the Cyber Museum is an accident, but soon they both begin searching for their father within the myths. As the series progresses, they realize that their search is much more important than they first realized, as Gorgos is bent on wiping out entire cultures by corrupting their mythologies.

It's not a perfect match to the description, as the boy and girl are siblings rather than neighbours, and the girl is wheelchair-bound, not the boy. Also, it's a computer program rather than a book that transports them into the bodies of mythological figures.

In the first episode, ["The Minotaur"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0655572/?ref_=ttep_ep1), the boy, Alex, is transported into the body of the Greek mythological figure of Theseus and ends up battling the Minotaur in King Minos' labyrinth. His sister, Cleo, stays in the real world, and observes what he's doing on a large, wall-mounted, flat screen monitor. They can also hear one another speak, so she helps him by providing intel on his situation.

In the third episode, "[Red Wolf's Daughter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0655568/?ref_=ttep_ep3)", Cleo is transported into the body of a Native American girl, and discovers she can walk while in that body. Alex stays in the real world and provides intel this time.

The seventh and eighth episodes, "[Isis & Osiris: Part 1](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0655563/?ref_=ttep_ep9)" and "[Isis & Osiris: Part 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0655564/?ref_=ttep_ep10)", take place in ancient Egypt.

You can view the scene where Alex is transported into the myth of Theseus at around the 12:50 mark in the video below.

Comment: Omg YES!!! I was remembering it all wrong. That’s how long it’s been lol I was like 10 when it came out.  thank you so much.

Comment: @Cedena Egnor - Glad to help. If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].